# API Method to track Android app Performance

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm writing a SpringBoot application that keeps statistics of our app. I want to be able to make a report of daily/monthly downloads of our app. So far, I've found [Andlytics](https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics), but the proyect is outdated. Is there a Google API that provides downloads data?

Can Analytics be used to make custom queries?

Answer (score 0):

After a cursory review of the Google Play Developer API [Reference](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref) and [Guide](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher), it does not look like they offer an explicit means of querying download statistics. You might start there to see if anything could be of use, though.

[Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics) would also be a good starting point.

> Link your Firebase app to BigQuery where you can perform custom analysis on your entire Analytics dataset and import other data sources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have done a lot of searching, and the feature apparently does not exists as of today. The closet I could find was creating custom reports with the [Analytics Reports API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4). There's no explicit downloads metric, but there is new users, which in some cases can be used to guesstimate.

Comment: @nazar that might be your best bet until something better rolls out, good luck!